# ALS.checkpointInterval and SparkContext.setCheckpointDir

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, pyspark

I was trying to look up what [`ALS.checkpointInterval`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.mllib.html#pyspark.mllib.clustering.LDA.train) does, but it wasn't very explanatory.

What is the difference between setting `ALS.checkpointInterval` and setting `sc.setCheckpointDir()`? Are both necessary, or do they work differently?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`SparkContext.setCheckpointDir` is used to set global checkpoint directory. It is not in limited to `ALS` or any other specific algorithm but it is required for `RDD.checkpoint` to work.

`ALS.checkpointInterval` is an algorithm specific property and doesn't affect any global settings. From ML docs:

> Param for set checkpoint interval (>= 1) or disable checkpoint (-1). E.g. 10 means that the cache will get checkpointed every 10 iterations.

Putting this two things together:

- this two thing work in a completely different context and have different consequences
- both are required for proper checkpointing in `ALS`. If checkpoint directory is not set [ALS won't checkpoint even if checkpoint interval is set](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ml/recommendation/ALS.scala#L638):

  ```scala
  val shouldCheckpoint: Int => Boolean = (iter) =>
    sc.checkpointDir.isDefined && 
    checkpointInterval != -1 &&
    (iter % checkpointInterval == 0)
  ```